# JQuery tabs - implementing in asp.net web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How do you implement this $.widget( "ui.tabs", {  that is already predefined in jquery-ui-1.8.24.js?

I've created a new web application and I notice in thw site.master there's:

```
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
```

and in the scripts folder and in jquery-ui-1.8.24.js there's a section about

```
        $.widget( "ui.tabs", {
```

I would have thought this is getting called throughout the site, with site.master containing the

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
```

as above.

I've added some tabs HTML but not getting called.

```
<div id="myTabs" style="width: 500px;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Title 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <p>
            tab 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <p>
            tab 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3">
        <p>
            tab 3
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#myTabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

hasn't jQuery already loaded with the tabs functionality?

Comment: What is showing you the Developer Console in your Browser?

Comment: You seem to have everything set up ok, but it looks like the js code isn't being loaded for that particular page.  As mentioned above, you can check this in Firebug's Javascript panel. A quick test would be to add a reference to jquery-ui-1.8.24.js directly in that page